# Resizable table with squared cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I'm writing a simple javascript powered game, and I've had the (unhappy?) idea to use a big html table to draw the scene of the game (a "pixel" is a cell).

Since the game must work on the main browsers at several screen resolution, but the "grid" size (number of cells) is always the same, I thought to set the table width to a percentage of the page width. Also, since the table is big (35 x 70), I generate it dynamically. In this way everything it's ok, but every table cell is (obviously) a rectangle, not a square.

So the question is: which is the best way to set the height of every `<td>` element the same of the width, considering that the width is known at runtime?

These are the interested pieces of code:

**HTML**:

```
<body>
    ...
    <div id="container"></div>
    ...
</body>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$("#container").html(createGrid(gridX,gridY));

function createGrid(row,col){
    var table="<table id='grid'>\n";
    for(i=0; i<row; i++){
        table+="<tr>"

    for(j=0; j<col; j++)
        table+="<td></td>"

    table+="</tr>\n";
    }
    table+="</table>";

    return table;
}
```

**CSS**:

```
#grid{
 position: relative;
 margin-left: auto ;
 margin-right: auto;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function you already know how many row you have, so

```
var winWidth = $(window).innerWidth(); //your window width
var gridWidth = winWidth/row; // each row width size
var heightWidth = $('tr').height(gridWidth); // set height
```